# using systemjs on node.js (& Angular 2)

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular, commonjs, systemjs

Say I have a foo.ts and app.ts as follows:

foo.ts:

```
 export interface Foo {
     id: number; 
     label: string;
 };
```

app.ts:

```
 import {Foo} from './foo'
 var myfoo: Foo = { "id": 1, "label": "One" };
 console.log(JSON.stringify(myfoo));
```

After compiling, executing `'node app.js'` from the command line runs as expected if I use `"module"="commonjs"` in my `tsconfig.json`. Cutting to the chase, what I would like to do is is use my `Foo` interface client-side with Angular 2, and server-side with node. Inconveniently, the Angular 2 quickstart I am modeling on [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) wants `"module"="system"` in `tsconfig.json`. This configuration causes an error when trying to run `'node app.js'`:

```
System.register([], function(exports_1) {
^
ReferenceError: System is not defined`
```

I have tried following the instructions for using systemjs with node on [github](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs), but at this point I am just mashing keys and could use some help. How do I either (a) get my app.ts code running on the server-side using systemjs, or alternately, (b) get the Angular 2 quickstart running with commonjs?

Comment: Are you sure you included "system.js" in your html ? Check your dev tools to be sure that all javascript files are loaded.

Comment: This is node.js on the server side, run from the command line. The client runs fine with the system.js and the Angular 2 quickstart tutorial. Except instead using lite-server like in the tutorial, I am using Node (+Express) to serve up the pages (+web services). But I can't get "system" to work on the server typescript code that wants to share interface Foo. What I am looking for is a simple typescript server-side node example that uses "system" instead of "commonjs".

Comment: To be clear, everything works fine if I write the server side in ES5 and traditional javascript. But I am hitting a wall trying to share typescript code on both the client and the server, with tsc -p . on the whole client&server project.

Comment: What I do is using gulp with to convert ts to js (with CommonJS), tsd (`tsd install node express`) for the "typings" and then running node. It's hard to see your problem without all the code.

Comment: The problem is the two module loading targets (system vs commonjs). And yes the solution appears to be to use different targets for the server and the client, managed with Gulp. What I was hoping was for a way to use system on the server code launched from the command line, as well as for the client, as in the Angular 2 quickstart tutorial. That way I can just have tsc -p on the whole project. All the code is in the OP. But it appears either that isn't possible, or no one cares because everyone uses Gulp.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue between angular2 and electron. Did you find a good way to fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It appears that the whole module loading thing is a dog's breakfast in ES6/Typescript land. At the time I posted I was coming off a traditional Java client/server world where relative sanity prevailed. There are no go-to texts I could find to refer to for what should be something pretty straightforward. Module loading in ES6/Typescript appears to be in a perpetual state of design-by-committee hell since at least 2011, AFAICT.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to wrap this up with an answer, even if the question hasn't been up-voted. The solution appears to be to use Gulp to compile the common typescript code (like interface Foo) differently for the client ("module"="system") and the server ("module"="commonjs"). If there is a way to compile the typescript code in the OP with "module"="system" I'd still like to know. But it appears to be kind of academic since everyone manages their project with Gulp or something similar anyway.

Comment: I use the same approach currently. But the downside is, that editors like visual studio mark dozens of errors with this approach.